# Need to correct code to merge workbooks in a single workbook - Eliminate Save Promt

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a code to merge multiple workbooks to a single workbook. However, it's prompting to save each file that's being transferred.

I need the data to be transferred without interruption for saving files.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
Sub Merger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("D:\change\to\excel\files\path\here")

Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts should help - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx

Comment: this is the best solution: `bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False`. See [Workbook Close event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx). This forces the workbook to close without saving changes. No prompts will appear.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should look into turning off display alerts to prevent notifications from appearing.

You can do this by turning it off using...
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

and back on using...
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.

Comment: while technically correct, i feel like `bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False` is much easier to implement and less of a hack since the argument is built into  the method itself  :)

Comment: Very much appreciated, gentlemen!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the AddIn from the link below is a lot easier to work with, and it handles all kinds of scenarios, so i twill do what you described here, as well as a lot of other things too.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm